# Using SDL_FillRect in a Snake game

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm having a problem with outputting a 'body'(single square) onto the screen in SDL using a linked list.

I have a `node` that has two data variables: a `node` pointer to the next, and a `SDL_Rect` value.

This is how I am calling the `SDL_FillRect` function:

```
node* tmp; 

SDL_FillRect(screen, &tmp->body, white);
```

Here is my node class:

```
class node{

    friend class map;

private:        
    node* next;

    SDL_Rect body;

public:         

    node() : next(NULL) {body.h = 15, body.w = 15, body.x = 390, body.y = 290;}

};
```

However when I call

```
node tmp; 

SDL_FillRect(screen, &tmp.body, white);
```

Where the `node` is not a pointer, the square outputs fine.

Any tips on how to get this to work with pointers to a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  node* tmp;
  SDL_FillRect(screen, &tmp->body, white);
```

You don't seem to allocate the object tmp. There should a `tmp = new node;` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
node* tmp;
```

you are only declaring a pointer to object from class 'node' but you are not instantiating an object from the class (if you want to get the SDL_Rect inside will be nothing on it, is just a pointer).

The other way:

```
node tmp;
```

you are instantiating the class, thats a correct way, if you want to pass a pointer and not the direction as you are doing in here:

```
SDL_FillRect(screen, &tmp->body, white);
```

you should instantiate the class this way to make your pointer point to something:

node* tmp = new node;

Only then you can obtain something from your pointer as this:

```
SDL_FillRect(screen, tmp->body, white);
```